# What's the proper command that generates a specific route that I should add to ubuntu?

Tags: networking, virtualization, 21.04, network-bridge

I'm trying to understand why there aren't any linux vm that can connect to internet if emulated with bhyve (it's level 2 hypervisor which run on freebsd 13). Instead,if I use vm-bhyve (a wrapper for bhyve) they can.

I've compared the routes added by vm-bhyve and by bhyve,to try to understand why the first one allows any linux distro to connect to internet and the second one,doesn't,and I found that the route below is added by vm-bhyve but not by bhyve. I tried to add it manually inside ubuntu using this command :

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1 enp0s5
```

but,instead of adding `192.168.1.1`,it adds `_gateway`. I think that it is the reason why it does not work. Also the metric should be changed. The right one is 100,but the command that I have issued doesnt add 100,but its still 0.

Does vm-bhyve add that route at the host level ? Since I'm not a coder,I'm not able to understand how works the vm-bhyve source code,I would like to know if I can add that route within ubuntu 21.04 guest os.

So,below you can see the route that works :

```
Destination = default 
gateway = 192.168.1.1
genmask = 0.0.0.0
flags = UG
metric = 100
ref = 0
use = 0
iface = enps05
```

and below you can see the route that's added manually when I issue the command **route add default gw 192.168.1.1 enp0s5** :

```
Destination = default 
gateway = _gateway
genmask = 0.0.0.0
flags = UG
metric = 0
ref = 0
use = 0
iface = enps05
```

maybe that command is wrong ? how it could be ?

Comment: What is that screenshot supposed to be? If that's your own text, please write it here as text.

Answer (score 0):

That would usually be be added via `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1` it will determine the interface that it can reach the GW with or you can specify it yourself `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s5`.
In general `ip` is preferred over the older route/ifconfig approach.

Comment: it isn't the solution for this problem. the solution is don't add the & character at the end of the bhyve pipeline command.